# How to display like Google

Tags: php

[If I search the word in Google is "twitter"](http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter).

Google displays the first result like the below.

```
Twitter
Twitter is without a doubt the best way to share and discover what is happening right now.
twitter.com/ - Cached - Similar

Search                 How To Contest Account Suspension
Blog                   An API
Twitter_logo_header    Twitter Status

More results from twitter.com »
```

How can they display Search, blog, Twitter_logo_header, etc.?

Comment: i dont really understand the question

Comment: Google will do that once your site is popular enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These links are called Site Links, and point to highly rated pages on your domain.

Usually these links are created automatically if your site is strong enough for a specific keyword, and you can tweak it a little by blocking pages you don't want to appear there from Google Webmaster Tools (http://google.com/webmasters) under 'Site Configuration', 'Sitelinks'.

More information on this topic available at the following Google help page - http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=47334&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This page explains how search engines like Google work:

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/search-engine.htm

Answer (score 0):

It's something google decides to do on its own. There is no way you can force them to do it with your site. They will do it if they find it appropriate.